# How to mock this MVC Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, mocking

I am using Fluent MVC to test some of my MVC controllers (some people argue this is not needed but this is more for a learning process rather than a production product).

**Interface**

```
public interface ISettings<T> where T : BaseSettingsDto
{
    T GetSettings();
    bool SaveSettings(T model);
}
```

**Implementing the interface**

```
public class GetSettingsConfiguration : ISettings<FirstSettingsDto>
{
    public FirstSettingsDto GetSettings()
    {
        var repo = new Repository();

        var result = repo.GetAll();
        // Do stuff
        return model;
    }

    public bool SaveSettings(FirstSettingsDto model)
    {
        var repo = new Repository();
        // Do stuff
    }
}
```

How I am using this in my controller (example):

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult GetInformation()
{
    var admin = new GetSettingsConfiguration();
    var config = admin.GetSettings();
}
```

How would I actually mock this out since the Interface is using generics?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can save ISettings as controller class field and init it from constructor parameter.

```
public Controller
{

  private ISettings<FirstSettingsDto> _admin;

  public Controller(ISettings<FirstSettingsDto> admin = null)
  {
    _admin = admin ?? new GetSettingsConfiguration();
  }

  [HttpGet]
  public ActionResult GetInformation()
  {
      var config = _admin.GetSettings();
  }
}
```

Now you can create Controller with ISettings mock.

**UPDATE**: set default value for ctor parameter (thx @JB06)

Comment: What if he isn't using dependency injection?

Comment: He can create constructor without parameters or can set `admin' as optional

Comment: Thanks, I am not currently using DI, I just did `ctor : this(ISettings)` etc